# Preview Microsoft Project File (.mpp) file in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

According to link below, to preview files, .mpp files is not a supported type in list. Is there any way we can extend this list /configure somewhere in Microsoft Teams to add this extension to preview the .mpp file?

[File Types supported for preview MS Teams](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/file-types-supported-for-previewing-files-in-onedrive-sharepoint-and-teams-e054cd0f-8ef2-4ccb-937e-26e37419c5e4)

Answer (score 0):

There is not away to accomplish this OOTB.